# Nestedscrollview end animation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-nestedscrollview

I have nestedscrollview:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <include
        ... />

    <include
        ..../>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_inserts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My nested scrollview dont have the animation at the end(wave). How to enable it?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your `NestedScrollView`

Comment: You can set the over scroll mode for this content as `android:overScrollMode="always"` in your `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma thanks, but it didnt solved my problem.

Comment: @HeisenBrg thanks, but it didnt solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean overScrollMode? Try this:

`android:overScrollMode="always"`